# Scroll on a non-active window

Tags: gratis, windows-7, mouse

In OSX, there is a handy feature where you can scroll (with the mouse) on any window that the mouse is above.

For example: I have a Google Chrome Window and a Microsoft Word window. I'm searching in Google Chrome, but I need to check something in my document, so, I scroll *on top* of that window and it starts scrolling, while being inactive.

Is there a **free** program for **Windows 7** that can replicate this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Wizmouse](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/). It's a free and lightweight program that allows you to scroll windows under the cursur even when they are out of focus. It works by converting the wheel movement into scroll commands. I used to have the same problem with Windows 7 after getting used to that feature in Kubuntu.

Another good thing about Wizmouse is that it also has a portable version which can be launched from a USB stick without the need for installation. Perfect for work environments